# Using gurobi solver with license in google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, pyomo, gurobi

I want to use gurobi solver in google colab using pyomo instead of glpk. I have a large problem, so I require an academic license to use it. I have two options to request an academic license.

My questions are:

1. Which of the following licenses below do I need to request in order to use it in google colab?

   [image]
2. How can I insert my academic license in code using google colab?

Could you please provide a simple code example?

Comment: It seems like you'd have to go with "Academic WLS License" in order to run on a virtual machine like colab. Though "Academic Gurobi Cloud License" or "Academic Cloud" is also an option, you'd be responsible for the cost of cloud resource usage. An academic license could be obtained by inputting your university credentials (assuming you're faculty and the university is pre-approved) otherwise you might have to ask the university for accessibility.